# C# AesGcm Authentication Tag

Tags: c#, encryption

I am currently having trouble implementing the `AesGcm` provider in C#. I am able to encrypt the data and decrypt it ONCE. After I have decrypted it the first time, I am unable to decrypt it again. It is giving me the following error:

`The computed authentication tag did not match the input authentication tag.`

I have tried changing the Tag, I have tried changing the Tag bytes, I've tried moving the tag inside the methods. I have absolutely no idea why I can encrypt the data without a problem but can only decrypt it once.

Here is my code:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Random tag for encryption and decryption
    /// Hardcoded so that the value is hard to retrieve
    /// No need to recycle this if changing encryption
    /// </summary>
    private static readonly byte[] Tag =
        {123, 89, 250, 199, 206, 135, 79, 86, 168, 237, 228, 163, 152, 134, 233, 88};

    /// <summary>
    /// Logger to enable the service to log
    /// </summary>
    private readonly ILogger<AesGcmEncryptionService> _logger;

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor for encryption service
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="logger">DI logger to use</param>
    public AesGcmEncryptionService(ILogger<AesGcmEncryptionService> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Method to encrypt a string with specified IV and key
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dataToEncrypt">Clear text string of data to encrypt</param>
    /// <param name="key">Base64 encoded byte array of the key</param>
    /// <param name="iv">Base64 encoded byte array of the IV</param>
    /// <returns>Base64 encoded byte array of encrypted data</returns>
    public string Encrypt(string dataToEncrypt, string key, string iv)
    {
        //Check that all the properties are populated
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dataToEncrypt) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(key) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(iv))
        {
            //Log the warning (not really an error)
            _logger.LogWarning("Encryption failed. Missing parameters!");
            //Return empty string
            return string.Empty;
        }

        try
        {
            //Take data to byte array
            var byteDataToEncrypt = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dataToEncrypt);
            //Take the key to byte array
            var byteKey = Convert.FromBase64String(key);
            //Take IV/Nonce to byte array
            var byteIv = Convert.FromBase64String(iv);

            //Declare variable to receive ciphertext
            var encryptedData = new byte[byteDataToEncrypt.Length];

            //Create new instance of AES-GCM provider
            var aesGcm = new AesGcm(byteKey);
            //Encrypt the data
            aesGcm.Encrypt(byteIv, byteDataToEncrypt, encryptedData, Tag);

            //Take the encrypted ciphertext to Base64
            return Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedData);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Log error for the exception
            _logger.LogError("Exception has occured whilst encrypting data. Ex: {ex}", ex);
            //Return an empty string
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Method to decrypt a string with specified IV and key
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dataToDecrypt">Base64 string of data to decrypt</param>
    /// <param name="key">Base64 encoded byte array of the key</param>
    /// <param name="iv">Base64 encoded byte array of the IV</param>
    /// <param name="base64">Whether the result should return base64 instead of a string</param>
    /// <returns>String of decrypted data</returns>
    public string Decrypt(string dataToDecrypt, string key, string iv, bool base64 = false)
    {
        //Check that all the properties are populated
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dataToDecrypt) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(key) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(iv))
        {
            //Log the warning (not really an error)
            _logger.LogWarning("Decryption failed. Missing parameters!");
            //Return empty string
            return string.Empty;
        }

        try
        {
            //Take data to byte array
            var byteDataToDecrypt = Convert.FromBase64String(dataToDecrypt);
            //Take the key to byte array
            var byteKey = Convert.FromBase64String(key);
            //Take IV/Nonce to byte array
            var byteIv = Convert.FromBase64String(iv);

            //Declare variable to receive plain text
            var decryptedData = new byte[byteDataToDecrypt.Length];

            //Create new instance of AES-GCM provider
            var aesGcm = new AesGcm(byteKey);
            //Encrypt the data
            aesGcm.Decrypt(byteIv, byteDataToDecrypt, Tag, decryptedData);

            //Return either a base64 string for byte array or take byte array to text
            return base64 ? Convert.ToBase64String(decryptedData) : Encoding.ASCII.GetString(decryptedData);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Log error for the exception
            _logger.LogError("Exception has occured whilst decrypting data. Ex: {ex}", ex);
            //Return an empty string
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Method to generate derive a key for the users password
    /// Key: 32 Bytes
    /// IV: 12 Bytes
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="password">Users password to generate key to use on login</param>
    /// <param name="keyBytes">Amount of bytes to generate</param>
    /// <returns>Base64 string of the key</returns>
    public string GenerateKey(string password, int keyBytes = 128)
    {
        //Salt for the password hashing
        byte[] salt =
            {123, 89, 250, 199, 206, 135, 79, 86, 168, 237, 228, 163, 152, 134, 233, 88};
        //Create keygen with the parameters for a new byte array
        var keyGenerator = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, salt, 49357);
        //Convert the bytes generated to Base64 string
        return Convert.ToBase64String(keyGenerator.GetBytes(keyBytes));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Method to generate CSPRNG random key
    /// Key: 32 Bytes
    /// IV: 12 Bytes
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="size">Byte size of the key</param>
    /// <returns>Base64 string of the random key</returns>
    public string GenerateRandomKey(int size = 32)
    {
        //Secure random number generator
        using RandomNumberGenerator rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
        //Instantiate the new byte array for storage
        var key = new byte[size];
        //Fill the array with random byte information
        rng.GetBytes(key);
        //Convert byte array to Base64 string
        return Convert.ToBase64String(key);
    }
```

Here is the calling code, which works once then not again:

```
    public LoginResult Login(string emailAddress, string password)
    {
        try
        {
            //Get the user with the email address provided
            var user = _repository.GetUserByEmailAddress(emailAddress);

            //Check that user was actually found
            if (user == null)
                //Return failure
                return new LoginResult();

            //Verify that the password is correct
            if (!Argon2.Verify(user.Password, password))
                //Return failure
                return new LoginResult();

            //Derive the users unique key to decrypt the actual encryption key
            var key = _encryptionService.GenerateKey(password);
            //Decrypt the encryption key from the database
            var base64EncryptionKey = _encryptionService.Decrypt(user.EncryptionKey, key, user.InitializationVector, true);

            //Return the login result
            return new LoginResult
            {
                IsSuccessful = true,
                DecryptedKey = base64EncryptionKey,
                InitializationVector = user.InitializationVector
            };
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Log exception for authentication failure
            _logger.LogError("Failed to authenticate user: {exception}", ex);
            //Return failure
            return new LoginResult();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Post the code where the first decryption is successful and the subsequent one fails. This may be because you store the tag in a field, and your implementation is trying to decrypt a ciphertext with a non-matching tag. Just a guess, please post the code.

Comment: @Topaco - I have added the calling code

Comment: To decrypt the ciphertext, the corresponding authentication tag is required in addition to the key and IV (it must be the specific tag generated during encryption). Is this tag used for decryption? Why is it not passed in the `Decrypt` method?

Comment: If you have a look at the Decrypt method it uses the same Tag as the encrypt does:

```aesGcm.Decrypt(byteIv, byteDataToDecrypt, Tag, decryptedData)```

Comment: In your code, the (static) `Tag` field is filled with _content 1_ when encrypting _plaintext 1_, and with a different _content 2_ when encrypting _plaintext 2_ (different from _plaintext 1_). When decrypting _plaintext 1_, the tag with _content 2_ is used, so that the decryption fails. It would be correct to store the tag associated with a ciphertext along with this ciphertext. Debug to check if the tags are really identical during encryption and decryption. With regard to the error message probably not.

Comment: Ah I see, that is the issue. Just verified it with the debugger. Didn't think of that. Thank you!